# How to define permissions in Django without staff status?

Tags: django, django-permissions

I'd like to give permissions to certain users to create articles, without assigning them staff status.

The reason is that I don't want any user to reach admin panel to authenticate, as happens when one adds `@staff_member_required` to a view. Instead I just want to add a `/add/article` link to the profile of users who have such permission.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using traditional functional views, you could do something like this:

```
def add_article(request):
    if not request.user.has_perm('articles.add_article'):
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    # Now only users that have the permission will reach this 
    # so add your normal view handling
```

However, I propose instead of the above, to use the `django.contrib.auth.decorators.permission_required` decorator:

```
@permission_required('articles.add_article')
def add_article(request):
    # your normal view handling
```

If you are using CBVs instead, you should either decorate the `as_view()` method of your CBV (in your `urls.py`) or use the `PermissionRequiredMixin` from django-braces (http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/access.html#permissionrequiredmixin) - or just do your own checks in the `dispatch()` method of the CBV.

Also, in your template put your add_article url inside a perms check, like this:

```
{% if perms.articles.add_article %}
     Show url for article editing only to users that have the rpmission
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I use transitional functional views. Great help. Thanks Serafeim.